# Remove item in dropdown when it is selected on another dropdown list

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, removechild

May I know how could I remove the item from a dropdown list when it is being selected on another dropdown list. Everytime I load the page , they would only show 1 dropdown list unless I click on the add button.

Example if I have 2 dropdown , dropdownA and dropdownB and I clicked on an item on dropdownA , I would like the item to be remove on dropdownB , the dropdownlist are stored in a kendo container .Hope that someone could help me. Thank you.

```
<select class="form-control required " name="acc">
            @foreach (Accessory acc in Acc)
            {
                    <option value="@acc.id">@acc.name</option>
            }
        </select>



function add()
{
    kendo.ui.progress($(".acc-container"), false);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Acc/GetAccesory",
        type: "POST",
        data: { ,
        success: function (retdata) {
            $(".acc-container").append(retdata);
            $(".acc-container").append("<hr />");
            $(".accessory" + formindex).select2();
            kendo.ui.progress($(".acc-container"), false);

            formindex++;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this like

```
$('#dropdown1').on('change', function () {  


var x = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();

var selectobject=document.getElementById("dropdown2")
  for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){
  if (selectobject.options[i].value == x )
     selectobject.remove(i);
  }



})
```

Comment: Sorry but the code for the dropdown is only one line which uses the foreach to loop it, may I know where can I define dropdown1 and dropdown2? Thank you.
@Mussaib Siddiqui

Comment: Where i define dropdown1 and dropdown2 in my answer, you simply write id of your both dropdown

Comment: But the code for both dropdown1 and dropdown2 are together? Sorry, I am unsure

Comment: function onDropDownBinding(e) {
            var id = this.element.attr("id");
          }

Comment: Man you have to just pick the id of both dropdowns by my comment or define id in html attribute of kendo dropdown then my answer will work